# xcode-select: command not found despite

Tags: xcode

I am trying to get Xcode and the command line developer tools working in order to use MacPorts.
I have installed Xcode and Xcode command line developer tools.

But when I try to use xcode-select I get:

```
xcode-select
-bash: xcode-select: command not found
```

And MacPort thinks that XCode is not installed:

```
sudo port install texlive
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
```

My `$PATH`looks like normal:

```
echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

I can't find the xcode-select utility anywhere:

```
sudo find / -iname xcode-select
```

I have tried deleting and reinstalling XCode and the command line tools from scratch, with multiple reboots. No effect. My current system is OSX 10.9.5 and XCode 6.0.1.

Can anybody help please?

Thanks

Comment: You can change the setting within Xcode as well: Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools

Comment: Thanks. I just tried it. But Xcode freezes when I try to access "Locations". All other settings work. Behaviour is the same after reinstalling. Looks like the issue runs deeper than I thought.

Answer (score -1):

If anybody encounters this issue:

xcode-select is now part of OS X, so if you don't have it the only solution I found is to backup everything and reinstall OS X.

See the help I received on Apple developer forum: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1050807#1050807